# R Multiply columns based on header name with values from second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. The first one is the output of a survey tool (df1), the second one contains the scoring/legend (df2). The df1 contains some demographic info and about 360 "question outcome id" (qo_id = qo1~qo360) each of which is either 0 or 1. df1 is dynamic so the order of columns can change. df2 contains the scoring for each qo_id. The real output is actually the sum of one or more specific "qo_id"s

df1 format

```
user_id age  gender  qo354 qo355 qo356 qo19 qo65 qo98
abc     34   f       1     0     0     0    1    1
def     40   m       0     1     0     0    0    1
ghi     28   f       0     0     1     1    1    0
```

df2 format

```
qo_id scoring outcome
qo354 -1      out4
qo355 0       out4
qo356 1       out4
qo19  1       out15
qo65  2       out21
qo98  1       out15
```

**Step 1** Problem: I want to multiply each qo_id (where qo_id=1) with their respective scoring.

```
user_id age  gender  qo354 qo355 qo356 qo19 qo65 qo98
abc     34   f       -1    0     0     0    2    1
def     40   m       0     0     0     0    0    1
ghi     28   f       0     0     1     1    2    0
```

The best thing I could come up with for step 1 is the below. However, it turns the demographic info to NA and there are actually some qo_id which do not have any scoring, these turn NA as well.

```
df <- df1*df2$scoring[match(names(df1), df2$qo_id)][col(df1)]
```

**Step 2** Problem: I want to add the outcomes to df1, so it looks like this.

```
user_id age  gender  qo354 qo355 qo356 qo19 qo65 qo98 out4 out15 out21
abc     34   f       -1    0     0     0    2    1    -1   1     2
def     40   m       0     0     0     0    0    1    0    1     0
ghi     28   f       0     0     1     1    2    0    1    1     2
```

I have a primitive rowSums solution for the second part, see below, but something automated would be great.

```
df1$out4<- rowSums(df1[, c("qo354", "qo355", "qo356")])
df1$out15<- rowSums(df1[, c("qo19", "qo98")])
df1$out21<- rowSums(df1[, c("qo21")])
```

I'm very much a noob at this and would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: have you seen [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) website ? I think your problems are linked to the way your datas are organised. All your data manipulation can be much more easier if you try to use "tidy" datasets. (sorry for updating my comment so much, I am not used to comment yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility addressing the first problem:

```
data.frame(df1[1:3],
           sweep(df1[4:length(df1)], 2, setNames(df2$scoring, df2$qo_id), "*"))

  user_id age gender qo354 qo355 qo356 qo19 qo65 qo98
1     abc  34      f    -1     0     0    0    2    1
2     def  40      m     0     0     0    0    0    1
3     ghi  28      f     0     0     1    1    2    0
```